# Getting object field previous value hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jpa, annotations

Let's assume I have this class :

```
@EntityListeners({MyListener.class})
class MyClass {
  String name;
  String surname;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name; 
  }

  public String getSurname() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setSurname(String name) {
    this.name = name; 
  }

  public void save() {
    JPA.em().persist(this);
    return this;
  }

  public void update() {
    JPA.em().merge(this);
  }

  public static MyClass findById(Long id) {
    return JPA.em().find(MyClass.class, id);
  }
}
```

Now in my `MyListener` class I'm trying to figure out the previous value `MyClass` instance versus the new value that is about to get saved(updated) to database. I do this with preupdate metdhod :

```
@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate(Object entity) {
...some logic here...unable to get the old object value in here           
}
```

So assuming I have a `MyClass` objects instance with name and surname :

```
MyClass mycls = new MyClass();
mycls.setName("Bob");
mycls.setSurname("Dylan");
mycls.save();
```

This wasn't picked up by listener which is ok because I'm listening only to updates. 
Now if I were to update this instance like so :

```
MyClass cls = MyClass.findById(someLongId)
cls.setSurname("Marley");
cls.update();
```

So this triggers the `preUpdate` method in mylistener and when I try to :

```
MyClass.findById(someLongId);
```

When I debug I already get the newly updated instance but the update hasn't happened yet because when I check in database in column surname it's still `Dylan`.

How do I get the value from database in my `preUpdate` method and not the one I just updated?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think an easy way is to save the previous value in a transient variable that JPA will not persist.
So just introduce a variable previousSurname and save the actual value before you overwrite it in the setter.

If you want to save multiple properties it would be easy if your class `MyClass` is `Serializable.`

If so add a post load listener

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

     @Transient
     private transient MyClass savedState;

     @PostLoad
     private void saveState(){
        this.savedState = SerializationUtils.clone(this); // from apache commons-lang
     }

}
```

*But be aware that the `savedState` is a detached instance.*

You can then access the previous state in your `EntityListener`.

You can also move the `PostLoad` listener to the `EntityListener` class. But then you need access to the `savedState` field. I recommend to make it either package scoped or use a package scoped accessor and put `MyClass` and `MyListener` in the same package,

```
public class MyListener {

    @PostLoad
    private void saveState(MyClass myClass){
         myClass.saveState(SerializationUtils.clone(myClass)); // from apache commons-lang
    }

}

public class MyClass implements Serializable {

     @Transient
     private transient MyClass savedState;

     void saveState(MyClass savedState){
        this.savedState = savedState;
     }

}
```

Comment: Hi Rene, I don't have @PostLoad in my POJO class. I have it inside my entity listener

Comment: Ok, than you can move the code to the entity listener. I mean that the EntityListener creates a copy of the object on load and sets the field. Or is there anything that I miss?

Comment: but if I move this code to listener class, the instance of listener changes. so if I set the value to listener instance in postload, that instance is null in preupdate

Comment: @RenéLink Why is it easier if MyClass is Serializable? I ask this because in the hibernate documentation they have a similar example but they are not implementing Serializable: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html

Comment: @RenéLink ignore my previous comment, I found the answer. SerializationUtils.clone works only with Serializable objects