# Design Solution required to fetch all the previous values of Entity Class object in Java

Tags: java, database, design-patterns

I need some documentary suggestion or sudo code or any link to implement this design pattern. I have written a Entity(Pojo) class which represents all columns of a table. My requirement I want to write some design solutions , So that, if there are multiple changes occured, I should be able to track all the previous values of that entity.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/ and http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa.

Comment: Ya this is what i need to do. but, without using any hibernate/jpa related apis.. i need to write it using simple core java modules. What should be the approach to design it???

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a framework like hibernate envers.

But if you can't use a framework, you might want to implement a history tracking using `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate`.

1. When the entity is loaded save the actual state

   See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19313914/974186
2. Check if the entity has changed on `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate`
3. If necessary create a history entry

For example

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private Integer id;

  private String firstname;

  private String lastname;

  /**
   */
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  private List<PersonHistory> personHistories = new ArrayList<>();

  @Transient
  private transient Person previousPersonState;

  protected Person() {
    // JPA only
  }

  public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
  }

  @PostLoad
  private void saveState() {
    this.previousPersonState = SerializationUtils.clone(this); // from apache commons-lang
  }

  @PrePersist
  @PreUpdate
  private void updateHistory() {
    if (personChanged()) {
      PersonHistory personHistory = new PersonHistory(previousPersonState);
      personHistories.add(personHistory);
    }
  }

  public boolean personChanged() {
    if (previousPersonState == null) {
      return false;
    }

    if (getFirstname() != null ? !getFirstname().equals(previousPersonState.getFirstname()) : previousPersonState.getFirstname() != null)
      return false;
    if (getLastname() != null ? !getLastname().equals(previousPersonState.getLastname()) : previousPersonState.getLastname() != null)
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
  }

  public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
  }
}
```

and the PersonHistory might look like this

```
@Entity
public class PersonHistory  {

  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
  private Person person;

  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;

  private Date createdDate;

  protected PersonHistory(){
    // default constructor for JPA    
  }

  public PersonHistory(Person person) {
    this.person = Objects.requireNonNull(person);

    this.firstname = person.getFirstname();
    this.lastname = person.getLastname();

    createdDate = new Date();
  }

  public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
  }

  public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
  }

  public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
  }
}
```